# Can't Find a Solution for Removing Trailing Slash at End of Directory URL

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please help me get my URL folders to point to index.php without a slash at the end. [I tried this guide,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235180/how-to-remove-trailing-slash-for-folder-index-html-when-index-html-is-stri/13238400#13238400)  but all I get is a URL with the slash at the end of it. The computer displays the right page, which is index.php, but the link ends with a slash.

Here's the .htaccess file:

```
# Turn MultiViews off. (MultiViews on causes /abc to go to /abc.ext.) 
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# It stops DirectorySlash from being processed if mod_rewrite isn't. 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Disable mod_dir adding missing trailing slashes to directory requests.
    DirectorySlash Off

    RewriteEngine On

    # If it's a request to index(.html) 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index(\.html)?(\?.*)?\  [NC]
    # Remove it. 
    RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index(\.html)?$ /%1 [R=301,L]

# if request has a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/$
# but it isn't a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-d
# and if the trailing slash is removed and a .html appended to the end, it IS a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
# redirect without trailing slash
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

# Add missing trailing slashes to directories if a matching .html does not exist. 
# If it's a request to a directory. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ -d
# And a HTML file does not (!) exist.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
# And there is not trailing slash redirect to add it. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

    # Remove HTML extensions. 
    # If it's a request from a browser, not an internal request by Apache/mod_rewrite. 
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    # And the request has a HTML extension. Redirect to remove it. 
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the request exists with a .html extension. 
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
    # And there is no trailing slash, rewrite to add the .html extension. 
    RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a HTML file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
# And there is a trailing slash redirect to remove it. 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]   


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# And a HTML file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
# And there is no trailing slash show the index.html. 
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [L]    

    </IfModule>
```

I can rewrite files to not have an extension and slash, but I want to be able to link to directories and load a file with no slash at the end of the browser URL. Please help.

Comment: When you say link, what do you mean?  In the browser url box?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean

Comment: Its too complicated for me.  I would suggest that you forget about index.html.  If its present in a directory, it will get executed or you will get a 404.  Have a look at the answer to my [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138463/how-can-i-have-either-php-or-html-file-running-whichever-exists).

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway

Comment: Have you tried? ``RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f``

Comment: Still adds a slash at the end of the URL